# How To Setup A "Services" List Using Header Tags, But Without Keyword Stuffing?

Tags: seo, heading, keyword-stuffing

I have a client with very little text on his site, and I would like to make the most out of his services page. The only information on this particular page are the names of the services. ie:

- *Painting*
- *Remodeling*
- *Countertops*
- *Etc.*

I would like to turn these (they're either `p` or `li` tags right now) into header tags so Search Engines understand that these are very important to the site, but without supporting content, I imagine this will be viewed as keyword stuffing. I'm thinking maybe I should make the more prominent services h2s and the not as prominent ones h3s/h4s? Would this approach improve or hinder my SEO?

*On other pages, he does have images with alt tags reiterating his key services*

Comment: Headers by themselves are of no value. You will absolutely need content following each one.

Comment: Additionally, those aren't headers. You shouldn't abuse HTML tags for the sake of SEO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of tag used when adding a piece of text to a page does not in and of itself affect the SERP ranking for the page in question. You should always use HTML tags for the correct purposes for situations where users are using an assisted device such as a screen reader which depends on the correct usage of HTML tags to work right.

In this instance you may be better served to list each service, and then beneath each service add a short couple of sentences which describe the service in question and make the service name a link to the service page details.

The whole point of SEO is to improve the quality of the page for the end user, and by doing things that will improve the end user's value derived from the site you will naturally be improving the sites quality for SEO and SERP ranking as well.